# Recover Google Chrome passwords from dead Windows

Tags: passwords, windows, google-chrome

I'm reinstalling Windows on a notebook. But that Windows won't start and I need the passwords saved in Chrome. Is there any way to recover them? The possible solutions I'm thinking about:

1. Boot some OS from USB and get passwords, but i don't know how they are protected. We have the Windows password.
2. Boot Windows from USB and try to start the old Chrome? Or install new Chrome and try to open passwords via new Chrome?

Comment: Just copy the Google Chrome user profile and transfer it to a external storage device.  This request you boot into Windows or another OS to access the directory.  If you cannot access the Google User profile directory then the profile cannot be backed up.  If you did not sync your passwords to the cloud then the only copy of your passwords cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 2):

Nirsoft's ChromePass could be used to do this simply.

You'll only have to go to File->advanced options and specify your user profile folder(the backup), as well as the password for that user profile.

Answer (score 0):

If she set up Chrome with a Google account then you won't need to get back on the computer. Due to Google backing up your passwords online. You should be able to access them by logging into the Google [Passwords](http://passwords.google.com) Website with the same log in information used to log into Chrome.